# Specific Twitter users not returning tweets with user_timeline()

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to get the latest Tweets from different users, and each one that I've tried with the exact same code works except for [this user](https://twitter.com/Millions). Here is the code that I tried:

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweet = api.user_timeline(screen_name='millions',
                          # 200 is the maximum allowed count
                          count=1,
                          include_rts=False,
                          tweet_mode='extended',
                          exclude_replies=True,
                          include_entities=True
                          )
print(tweet)
```

It just prints `[]` for me, and if I change the user to someone else, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that it brings the amount of "count" and then filters (in this case the rt and replies). From the [doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline):

**exclude_replies**:

> Using exclude_replies with the count parameter will mean you will receive up-to count tweets — this is because the count parameter retrieves that many Tweets before filtering out retweets and replies.

**include_rts**:

> When set to false , the timeline will strip any native retweets (though they will still count toward both the maximal length of the timeline and the slice selected by the count parameter)

So if you bring just one and it's an rt (or a reply) you'll be left with an empty list.

And it is the same to bring 1 or 200, both count as a single api call. So it is better to bring more and stay with the first:

```py
tweet = api.user_timeline(screen_name='millions',
                          count=200,
                          include_rts=False,
                          tweet_mode='extended',
                          exclude_replies=True,
                          include_entities=True
                          )
# keep only the first tweet
tweet = tweet[:1]
```